# Can't fix "Module build failed: SyntaxError:: Unexpected token" error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

As far as i can know i have the right .babelrc and webpack.config setup but still getting the Module build failed: SyntaxError on npm start.

```
    ERROR in ./src/components/Nav.js
    Module build failed: SyntaxError: /Users/me/project/src/components/Nav.js: Unexpected token (24:69)
      22 |             <LoadingButton className="btn--nav" />
      23 |           ) : (
    > 24 |             <a href="#" className="btn btn--login btn--nav" onClick={::this._logout}>Logout</a>
         |                                                                      ^
      25 |           )}
      26 |         </div>
      27 |       ) : (
```

my `.babelrc` files looks like:

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-1"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": [
        "react-hmre"
      ]
    },
    "production": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-react-constant-elements",
        "transform-react-remove-prop-types"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and `webpack.config` file (abbreviated):

```
module: {
            loaders: [
              {test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel', exclude: path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/'), include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')},
              {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
              {test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"},
              {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
              {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'},
              {test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i, loaders: ['file']},
              {test: /\.ico$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'},
              {test: /(\.css|\.scss)$/, loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'postcss', 'sass?sourceMap']}
            ]
          }
```

Can anyone please point out my mistake here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bind operator :: is not included in ES6 (also known as ECMA2015), it is only a proposed language feature. You're using a babel preset for ECMA2015 (es2015) so it won't recognize :: as a valid operator. You can easily solve that by just using the good ol' .bind function or an arrow function to capture the 'this' context.

So, instead of writing `onClick={::this._logout}`

You can write:

1) `onClick={ this._logout.bind(this) }`

2) `onClick={ () => { this._logout() } }`

Comment: "ES7" is already standardized and released, bind syntax is not part of it. It's best to just call these things proposed language features.